# Почему запрос в TOAD работает корректно, а в SQLTools - ошибка?

Tags: oracle, sql

Запрос:

```
SELECT to_date(DH.LAST_STATE_CHANGED, 'dd.mm.yy') FROM os_doc.document_header dh
```

Ошибка:

> ORA-01861: литерал не соответствует формату строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разный NLS_DATE_FORMAT в каждом из инструментов.

Answer (score 5):

Колонка `last_state_changed` в SQL выражении используется неверно. Возможно в каком то инструменте и будет работать, но не надо полагаться на случай.
Правильно так:

```
select to_char (dh.last_state_changed, 'dd.mm.yy') 
from os_doc.document_header dh
```

---

Почему так?

Колонка `document_header.last_state_changed` имеет тип данных `DATE` (объявление как `VARCHAR2` не будем расматривать, т.к. это было бы ошибкой при разработке схемы БД):

1. Данные сначала **неявно** конвертируются в `VARCHAR2`. т.к. перегруженая функция `to_date (dt date, format varchar2)` отсутствует как бессмысленная.
2. Далее, данные **явно** конвертируются в тип данных `DATE` используя маску формата `'dd.mm.yy'`.
3. В заключении, так как внутреннее представление типа данных DATE не совсем "читабельно", оно **неявно** конвертируется снова в символьное представление.

Во всех случаях неявного конвертирования используется значение `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, которое может быть задано в реестре Windows, переменной окружения или в установках используемого инструмента.

При несовпадении этого значения с маской формата заданной явно, возникают различные ошибки конвертирования, зависящие от места, в котором символьный литерал не совпадает с маской формата:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
>   ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format