# Передача параметров в FastReport из c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp, fastreport

Пытаюсь передать цифры в стринговом формате в фаст репорт в sql запрос.
Но выдаёт ошибку:

```
Ошибка построения отчета: ORA-01861: литерал не соответствует формату строки
```

c#:

```
report.SetParameterValue("ClientOrderN", txbClientOrderNumber.Text);
report.SetParameterValue("ClientOrderI", txbClientOrderItem.Text)
```

часть sql запроса в fastreport:
(l.ORDER_NUMBER = (:ClientOrderNumber||'-'||:ClientOrederItem) or (:ClientOrderNumber is null and :ClientOrederItem is null)
ORDER_NUMBER типа varchar, параметры в fastreport типа variant. Кто знает в чём причина моей ошибки подскажите пожалуйста. Не как не могу разобраться.

```
select PIPE_NUMBER, PIPE_YEAR, WC_INSTANCE, WORKCENTER_ID, RETURN_REASON, DIAMETER, THICKNESS, MELT_NUMBER, PART_WELD, STEELMARK, VENDER, WAREHOUSE_BEFORE_MOVING, res_und_order, CREATE_DATE, INSERT_OPERATOR, Date_Cancel_With_Reserved, Operator_PRM,
case when  Date_Cancel_With_Reserved is not null and res_und_order = ORDER_NUMBER and RETURN_ADDRESS is null then 'Подтверждено'
when Date_Cancel_With_Reserved is not null and res_und_order <> ORDER_NUMBER and RETURN_ADDRESS is null then 'Не подтверждено'
else 'Активно' end as reserv_status
from(
select p.RETURN_ADDRESS, p.ORDER_NUMBER, m.PIPE_NUMBER, m.PIPE_YEAR, s.WC_INSTANCE, r.WORKCENTER_ID, s.RETURN_REASON, m.DIAMETER, m.THICKNESS, m.MELT_NUMBER, m.PART_WELD, m.STEELMARK, m.VENDER, s.WAREHOUSE_BEFORE_MOVING, s.ORDER_NUM_RES||'-'|| s.ORDER_ITEM_RES as res_und_order, s.CREATE_DATE, s.INSERT_OPERATOR, first_value(p.CREATE_DATE) over(partition by m.SHOP_ID, m.PIPE_YEAR, m.PIPE_NUMBER order by s.CREATE_DATE desc, p.CREATE_DATE nulls first) as Date_Cancel_With_Reserved, row_number() over(partition by m.SHOP_ID, m.PIPE_YEAR, m.PIPE_NUMBER order by p.CREATE_DATE) as RN, first_value(p.INSERT_OPERATOR) over(partition by m.SHOP_ID, m.PIPE_YEAR, m.PIPE_NUMBER order by s.CREATE_DATE desc, p.CREATE_DATE nulls first) as Operator_PRM from WC_MAIN m
left join WC_7_3_SGP s on m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p on m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER and p.EDIT_STATE = 0 and p.CREATE_DATE > s.CREATE_DATE
left join WC_1_2_LIST l on m.SHOP_ID = l.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = l.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = l.PIPE_NUMBER
left join ROUTE_PIPE_MOVES r on m.SHOP_ID = r.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = r.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = r.PIPE_NUMBER
where s.RETURN_ADDRESS is not null and s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null and s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null and m.EDIT_STATE = 0 and s.EDIT_STATE = 0 and l.EDIT_STATE = 0 and r.ACTION_DATE = (select max(ACTION_DATE) from ROUTE_PIPE_MOVES where PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER) and s.WC_INSTANCE = (select max(s.WC_INSTANCE) from WC_7_3_SGP s where s.PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER) and s.CREATE_DATE BETWEEN to_date(:START_DATE) and to_date(:END_DATE)
and (l.ORDER_NUMBER = (:ClientOrderNumber||'-'||:ClientOrederItem) or (:ClientOrderNumber is null and :ClientOrederItem is null)))
where RN = 1 and
(PIPE_NUMBER >= :PipeStart or :PipeStart is null)and
(PIPE_NUMBER <= :PipeEnd or :PipeEnd is null)and
(Date_Cancel_With_Reserved like to_date(:DateCancelReserv) or to_date(:DateCancelReserv) is null);
```

Comment: Добрый день. Судя по тексту ошибки - это ошибка на стороне оракла, такое обычно вылазит если пытаешься производить действия с разными типами данных. ORDER_NUMBER имеет известный формат, а вот как приходят твои параметры - неизвестно. Попробуй завернуть параметры в TO_CHAR().

Comment: И ещё. Я с fastreport не работал.. ты уверен, что проблемы именно в условии? Может в перечислении столбцов есть вычисления, к примеру с датой...

Comment: @Deft в sql-developer всё работает отлично с те ми же параметрами, в to_char уже пытался завернуть, толку чуть.

Comment: Запрос, который вы запускаете в sql-developer  - добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Deft добавил .

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в строке `to_date(:DateCancelReserv)`. Подобная проблема была вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-toad-%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B0-%D0%B2-sql-tools-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Т.е. разные настройки клиентов выводят дату в разных форматах и оракл не может выполнить to_date() в одном из случаев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобная проблема была [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-toad-%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B0-%D0%B2-sql-tools-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0).

> Разный NLS_DATE_FORMAT в каждом из инструментов.

Т.е. разные настройки клиентов выводят дату в разных форматах и оракл не может выполнить to_date() в одном из случаев.