# Как организовать процесс отслеживания изменений в объектах БД

Tags: c#, sql, алгоритм, oracle

Есть база данных, в ней таблицы, если в таблицы что то записалось или удалилось то эти изменения записываются в таблицу `TableChangeHistory`. Мое приложение должно  по запросу узнавать, в каких таблицах произошли изменения и выбирать данные из обновленных таблиц. Сама таблица выглядит так:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLECHANGEHISTORY
(
  TABLENAME     VARCHAR2(512 CHAR),
  MODIFIEDDATE  DATE,
  OBJIDS        VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
);

CREATE INDEX I_TCHIST_TNMODIFIED ON TABLECHANGEHISTORY (TABLENAME, MODIFIEDDATE);
```

В своем приложении я делаю такой запрос:

```
select to_char(max(modifieddate),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as lastmodifieddate,tablename 
from TableChangeHistory 
group by tablename;
```

В результате я получаю массив из данных, в которых вижу в каких таблицах произошли изменения. Думал как то поиграть со временем, ну например, смотреть изменения за сегодня, за час и т.д., но тогда я теряю данные, которые могли быть изменены раньше чем я из программы сделал запрос и не попал во временной промежуток, потому вот использую максимум. И тут у меня возникает делема, как запоминать уже имеющиеся результаты этого запроса. Вот например, я первый раз запустил программу, запрос мой выдал мне все измененные таблицы, я сделал выгрузку из этих таблиц, а дальше я должен сохранить как-то эти данные из запроса, о том какие таблицы изменены (в моем случае на выходе запроса я получаю массив), чтобы, например, если через 20 минут я снова нажму кнопку и запрос мне выдаст уже другую пачку измененных таблиц, и конечно же в этом запросе будут таблицы которые уже были в первом запросе и новые измененные таблицы.

Как отследить и провести сравнение на предмет того, что старое и что новое?

Comment: Добавьте таблицу с 3 полями - имя таблицы, штамп времени последнего обновления, штамп времени последнего запроса об обновлениях. Данные в ней пополняйте/обновляйте триггером на существующей таблице. Сведения об изменениях берите из неё. Заодно избавитесь от группировки. Сведения выгребаем запросом типа `UPDATE tab SET last_get=NOW WHERE last_get <= last_modif OUTPUT *`. Ну или UPDATE в CTE и SELECT в запросе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, подумаю, проблема тут будет в том, что мне нельзя вносить данные в саму базу, я могу только пользоваться данными об обновлении из этой таблицы. Хотя идея хорошая, может быть как то на моей стороне, на стороне приложения попробую что то сделать со штампом времени.

Comment: Ммм... не понял. БД доступна только в режиме Read-Only? PS. DBMS - Oracle Database? добавьте соотв. тег к вопросу.

Comment: Нет, просто  мне чтобы согласовать изменения бд нужно много времени)

Comment: @Akina А еще раз опишите логику подробнее, как мне работать современными штампами, и по каким условиям эти штампы будут отбираться, если я вас понял правильно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без изменений в БД решить не получится.

---

Самое простое, изменить уже существующую таблицу `TableChangeHistory`, добавив поле с маркером для уже просмотренных изменений:

```
alter table TableChangeHistory add (viewed char (1) default 'n');
```

Тогда запрос можно ограничить только теми изменениями, которые ещё были "не просмотрены":

```
select tablename, max (modifieddate) lastmodiefed 
from tablechangehistory
where viewed = 'n'
group by tablename
;
```

После обработки запроса, просмотренные записи надо отметить:

```
update tablechangehistory set
    viewed = 'y'
where <tablename, modifieddate из только что просмотренного массива>
;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, практически сработало, только у меня увы запрос на обновления имеет такой вид и выдается ошибка.

Comment: update tablechangehistory set viewed = 'y' where  tablename='TESTNAME20141030', modifieddate='2014-12-26 13:08:15';

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Что я не так написал в запросе?

Comment: `... and modifieddate=`. Всё, что между < > я схематически показал. Вы упомянали массив, но я же не знаю как он выглядит.

Comment: Да я также сделал с and , но выходит ошибка ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.  И теперь как бы мне привести запись эту modifieddate='2014-12-26 13:08:15' к формату даты, что в таблице или перевести в дату.

Comment: Так: `modifieddate=to_date ('2014-12-26 13:08:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39761) подробнее об этом.

Comment: Спасибо , заработало.

Comment: Вообще, если начинать реализацию с самого начала, я бы взял [CQN (Continuous Query Notification)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS018), это асинхронное оповещение при изменении результата запроса. Как раз подошло бы для данного случая.  Может и кнопку не надо было бы жать, всё было бы автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас посмотрю, но я ограничен в возможностях изменении базы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94901/discussion-between-vladimr-vladimirovoch-and-0xdb).

Answer (score 1):

@Vladimr Vladimirovoch. Чтобы была возможность смотреть динамику изменений- вам необходимо делать логирующие таблицы, для каждой из таблиц по которым нужна информация данного рода. Т.е. на таблицу вешается триггер, который записывает каждое изменение в другую таблицу(в лог вставляется запись) с меткой времени, когда была вставка/изменение/удаление каждой записи. Периодически лог очищается.

Answer (score 1):

Схема (плевать на синтаксис).

Создаём таблицу

```sql
CREATE TABLE last_changes ( tablename VARCHAR,
                            ts_change TIMESTAMP,
                            ts_get TIMESTAMP,
                            PRIMARY KEY (tablename) )
```

Создаём триггер фиксации факта изменения рабочих таблиц (вернее, поступления записи о таком изменении в таблицу истории изменений)

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER fix_changes
AFTER INSERT ON TableChangeHistory 
AS
MERGE INTO last_changes
USING (UPDATED.*) 
ON (tablename)
WHEN MATCHED THEN     -- имя уже присутствует, обновляем
    UPDATE SET ts_change = UPDATED.ModifiedDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- имя отсутствует - вставляем
    INSERT (tablename, ts_changed, ts_get)
    VALUES (UPDATED.TableName, UPDATED.ModifiedDate, UPDATED.ModifiedDate)
```

Когда необходимо получить сведения об изменившихся таблицах (вернее, просто список таких таблиц), выполняем

```sql
UPDATE last_changes 
SET ts_get = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ts_change >= ts_get -- только изменившиеся после предыдущего запроса
RETURNING (tablename)
```

Вот где-то так...

PS. Если фиксируется изменение таблиц более чем одной схемы/базы, в поле tablename пишем полное имя таблицы, с указанием схемы/БД.

Comment: Ок сейчас проверю, спасибо за ответ, логику увидел, попробую сейчас

Comment: С триггером увы ошибка оракл выдает ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification, а именно там где AS

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Ну я ж русским по белому пишу - не соблюдаю синтаксис! Уж такие-то мелочи можно дорихтовать самостоятельно? Тем более что Оракла у меня под рукой нет, и не предвидится.

Comment: Пробовал переделать то, что вы написали на оракл, увы не получается, 2 дня понратил на это)