# Конвертирование строки с числом заданой длины в значение времени

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Нужно конвертировать строку, в которой 4-х значные числа (например, `'0625'`) в строку времени формата "часы:минуты" (то есть, `'06:25'` в данном случае).

В таблице есть строчные колонки:

- `TIME` с 4-х значными числами
- `TIME2` куда нужно занести результат

Пробовал через функцию `TO_DATE`, но при следующий пример выдает неправильный результат:

```
UPDATE ATEST
SET TIME2 = TO_DATE("TIME", 'HH24:MI') 
WHERE ID > 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: TO_DATE("TIME", 'HH24MI')

Comment: Все равно в TIME2 отображается некорректная информация.

Comment: вы не с той стороны подошли к вопросу. У вас колонка time имеет какое нибудь отношение к ddate ? Если да, но дату и время надо хранить в одном поле типа date и тогда при выводе нужную маску зададите и все. А так как сейчас, когда время просто строка, то не надо пытаться работать с ней как с временем. работайте как со строкой, буквально `substr(time, 1, 2)||':'||substr(time, 3, 2)`

Comment: Вот это сработало! Согласен, можно работать просто со строкой. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Извините, но если вы считаете, что решение из комментария @Mike сработало, то ваш вопрос поставлен абсолютно неверно. В текущей постановке вопроса у вас ошибка  в маске 'HH24:MI' и первый комментарий дал правильное решение. Ваше утверждение, что  _в TIME2 отображается некорректная информация_, ничем не обоснованно.

Comment: @0xdb Там все поля текстовые, включая time и time2. Так что to_date делает нужное время сегодняшнего дня и при попытке записи его в текстовое поле конвертит по дефолтном для региона правилам в текст

Comment: @Mike Да, я заметил, но это же должно быть чётко оговорено в вопросе, а не строится путём догадок из скрина и комментариев. Пытался соподвинуть ТС улучшить вопрос, посмотрим, получится ли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';

UPDATE ATEST
  SET time2 = TO_TIMESTAMP(time, 'HH24MI') 
  WHERE id > 0;
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это уже работает, но хотелось бы покрасивее, только 4 числа, то есть "06:25", или максимум "06:25:00"

Comment: допилил ответ...

Comment: Сверху Mike подсказал вариант, но тут теперь тоже красиво работает. Спасибо!

Comment: там нужно со строками работать :-( , а это встроенный функционал Oracle

Answer (score 2):

Для преобразования строчного значения в строчное надо [воспользоваться функциями возвращающими строчное значение](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2).

Несмотря на наличие ключевого слова *время*, использовать функции по работе со временем, например, `to_timestamp` или `to_date`, не следует. О возмоожных ошибках при неявном преобразовании типа данных `date` в строку посмотрите, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842633/217579).

Попробовать результаты преобразования проще в анонимном блоке:

```sql
declare
    time constant varchar2 (4) := '0625';
    time2 varchar2 (24) := regexp_replace (time, '(\d{2})(\d{2})', '\1:\2');
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('new time(old time)='||time2||'('||time||')');
end;
```

> new time(old time)=06:25(0625)