# Смена даты в ячейке в зависимости от времени

Tags: sql, oracle

Продолжая данный вопрос:
[Конвертирование строки с числом заданой длины в значение времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091116/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8/1092980#1092980)

В таблице содержатся 6 колонок:

- `REG_ID` - идентификатор
- `DDATE` - дата события
- `DTIME` - время события в формате 4 цифр
- `DTIMEUTC` - время события по UTC в формате 4 цифр
- `DT_LOCAL` - конвертированное (в нормальном виде) дата и время события
- `DT_UTC` - конвертированное (в нормальном виде) дата и время события по UTC

Данные в первые 4 столбца занесены. В два последних столбца данные заносятся при помощи запросов, с которыми мне подсказали в предыдущем вопросе:

```
UPDATE ATEST
SET DT_LOCAL = "DDATE" || ' ' || SUBSTR(DTIME, 1, 2)|| ':' ||substr(DTIME, 3, 2)
WHERE REG_ID > 0

UPDATE ATEST
SET DT_UTC = "DDATE" || ' ' || SUBSTR(DTIMEUTC, 1, 2)|| ':' ||substr(DTIMEUTC, 3, 2)
WHERE REG_ID > 0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наконец, вопрос. Как видно по запросу и таблице, иногда время по UTC приходится уже на следующий день, и, соответственно, дата должна поменяться. То есть по примеру, в таблице вторая строка с временем по UTC уже должна быть 03.01.2010, а не 02.01.2010. Какой SQL запрос нужно сделать, чтобы дата в строке DT_UTC увеличивалась, если DTIMEUTC уже переходит на следующий день по сравнению с DTIME?
В данном примере данные в DT_UTC не совсем корректны, например, в 1 и 2 строке должно быть первое число, так как по UTC второе число еще не наступило. Время варьируется в пределах 12 часов.

Прикладываю запрос по созданию таблицы:

```
create table ATEST
(
  reg_id   NUMBER(19) not null,
  ddate    VARCHAR2(255),
  dtime    VARCHAR2(255),
  dt_local VARCHAR2(255),
  dt_utc   VARCHAR2(255),
  dtimeutc VARCHAR2(255)
)

insert into ATEST (reg_id, ddate, dtime, dt_local, dt_utc, dtimeutc)
values (1, '02.01.2010', '0125', '02.01.2010 01:25', '02.01.2010 22:25', '2225');
insert into ATEST (reg_id, ddate, dtime, dt_local, dt_utc, dtimeutc)
values (2, '02.01.2010', '0328', '02.01.2010 03:28', '02.01.2010 20:28', '2028');
insert into ATEST (reg_id, ddate, dtime, dt_local, dt_utc, dtimeutc)
values (3, '03.01.2010', '0645', '03.01.2010 06:45', '03.01.2010 02:45', '0245');
insert into ATEST (reg_id, ddate, dtime, dt_local, dt_utc, dtimeutc)
values (4, '03.01.2010', '1250', '03.01.2010 12:50', '03.01.2010 09:50', '0950');
insert into ATEST (reg_id, ddate, dtime, dt_local, dt_utc, dtimeutc)
values (5, '03.01.2010', '1845', '03.01.2010 18:45', '03.01.2010 15:45', '1545');
commit;
```

Comment: *Как видно* Мне, например, в упор не видно. Дата - второе. Время - полдвенадцатого. С какого перепугу дата должна стать третьим - я не понимаю, вот хоть режь.

Comment: В гипотетической ситуации время (во второй строчке) в одной стране 11:28, однако, из-за часовых поясов, в другой стране оно 02:28. Соответственно, и даты должны быть разные, во второй стране уже наступил следующий день. Надеюсь, так чуть-чуть понятнее.

Comment: Увы, из первого НИКАК не следует второе. Если по Гринвичу 2 с копейками, то 11 с копейками в GMT+7, скажем, в Новосибирске. И дата - то же самое второе.

Comment: Не храните даты и время в текстовом виде, в отдельных колонках. С ними невозможно нормально работать. Используйте тип DATE или возможно даже timestamp with timezone. Тогда вам потребуется всего одна колонка для хранения всего, что вы сейчас пытаетесь записать в 5 колонок. И из этого единственного значения вы всегда сможете получить любое из значений, хоть дату, хоть время. Причем в любом часовом поясе. И не придется писать кучу кода для перевода и сохранения в таблице других видов представления даты и времени. С текущей структурой БД вы придумали себе кучу проблем на ровном месте

Comment: @Akina , Ну, опять же, ситуация гипотетическая. Если в Москве, скажем, 22 часа, то в Новосибирске будет 02 ночи, соответственно, уже следующий день.

Comment: @Mike К сожалению, структуру таблицы придумывал не я..

Comment: *Ну, опять же, ситуация гипотетическая.* То, что в разных зонах дата может быть разной - я знаю. Абстрактно. Но, блин, Вы показываете вполне конкретные цифири, для которых эта дата ну ни фига не должна быть разной, и при этом утверждаете, что она должна.

Comment: Так тут в этом и задача) В колонке 2, 4 и 5 дата как раз разная, так как по UTC (аналог Гринвича) время уже в "следующем дне".
Думаю, стоит отметить, что в DT_UTC информация о датах неправильная, в 2, 4 и 5 строке должно быть уже 3 и 4 число соответственно.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что дата именно в этих строках должна увеличиться ? По текущим данным в таблице не ясно вообще к какому дню относиться время. Ведь 02:28 UTC может быть и в том же дне, что и 11:28 local в случае если часовой пояс UTC+09. Если вы считаете, что во второй строке время уже в следующем дне, то часовой пояс у вас должен быть UTC-15, а часовые пояса более +-12 часов не приняты

Comment: Я вот например могу утверждать, что в 3 строке неверная дата. Потому что часового пояса 20:45 - 06:45 = UTC-14 быть не может. Это часовой пояс UTC+10, а следовательно дата по UTC должна быть на день меньше

Comment: @Mike согласен, значит, дата может идти и назад, если по UTC время раньше, чем из DTIME.

Comment: Спасибо, Mike, Вы абсолютно правы. Сейчас поменяю скриншот на более корректную информацию.

Comment: Вы бы данные из этого примера дали бы в виде _текста_ (в идеале create table и insert). Набивать контрольный пример по фотографии лень. Плюс стоит переформулировать задачу, или изменить пример и сказать в каком часовом поясе расценивать инфу или сказать что часовой пояс надо рассчитать исходя из невозможности превышения разницы 12 часов (и тогда пример можно не менять)

Comment: Поменял, добавил, как смог.

Comment: Сами данные важнее, их долго забивать. Попробуйте экспортировать данные. Если у вас pl/sql developer, то там например есть экспорт в виде sql, который сам генерит нужные insert. Или можно в какой нибудь tsv, его отлично сайт sqlfiddle.com сконвертит в заполненную таблицу БД (Кнопка Text to DDL)

Comment: Добавил, готово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нам необходимо вычислить разницу в часах между двумя временами. Скорректировать ее в случае если превышает 12 часов, взяв оставшуюся часть суток. После чего вычесть полученное значение в часах из локальной даты-времени, получив таким образом дату-время UTC.

```
update atest
   set dt_utc = 
       to_char(
           to_date(dt_local, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') - 1 / 24 *
            case when abs((dtimeutc-dtime)/100) > 12
                 then (24 - abs((dtimeutc-dtime)/100)) * sign(dtimeutc-dtime)
                 else -(dtimeutc-dtime)/100
            end
       , 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
```

Пример вычисления новой даты на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/502760/2)

Comment: Работает, большое Вам спасибо.